Resource Override Python
I am using Chrome Resource Override extension in portable chrome. I am using Selenium Python in the project. But now I need to remove this extension. Can I do it using only Python? Can you help me?
I tried the code below but it didn't work.
def inject_local_js(driver, url_pattern, local_path):
    local_path_url = f'file:///{local_path.replace("\\", "/")}'
    script = f"""
    (function() {{
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {{
            if (scripts[i].src.includes("{url_pattern}")) {{
                scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
                var newScript = document.createElement('script');
                newScript.src = "{local_path_url}";
                document.head.appendChild(newScript);
                console.log('Replaced:', newScript.src);
            }}
        }}
    }})();
    """
    driver.execute_script(script)

url_pattern = 'https://wwww.com/js/web.js'
local_js_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/local.js'

inject_local_js(driver, url_pattern, local_js_path)


Please elaborate on your usecase a bit like - what were you doing with resource override(code sample seems to be inject script), why do you want to remove resource override etc. This will help other developers to understand your problem and help better.
